# Most recent messages with Strophe MAM

Tags: ejabberd, strophe

Am using ejabberd, with mod_mam - and strophe with mam plugin.  This is successfully retrieving ALL the messages for a user.

What we are trying to do is retrieve only the LAST 50 messages. Using the strophe mam "max": 50 setting returns just 50 messages, but it is the first 50 not the last.

The before 'RSM' setting requires we have the id of the last message - which we don't have because we have not yet queried MAM.

So the question is simply, how to get the last 50 jabber messages using strophejs mam

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer - you just need to pass a blank value for before:

```
"max": 100,
"before": '',
```

So this provides that last 100 messages

Comment: How did you managed to display the messages??  When i do onMessage:function(message) {console.log( $(message).text());}  It only log the last message, but not all of them.And i have no idea how to loop them through.

Comment: @John I know it's old question, but anyway... If you don't do a "return true" in onMessage() function, handler is removed and you process only single message.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `return true;` as the last line of `onMessage()` will solve the issue of getting only a single message.